# Multiple where conditions on entity causes read only property to be true

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, telerik-grid

I'm trying to filter the results from an entity, but when I put two where conditions before the load it'll only filter by the first condition like so

```
      _entity.LineItems.Where(x =>( x.EstID == Est.EstID) && (x.LineItemType == 1)).Load();
      radLaborLineItems.DataSource = _entity.LineItems.Local.ToBindingList();
```

Also tried it like this with the same results

```
     _entity.LineItems.Where(x => x.EstID == Est.EstID).Where(y => y.LineItemType == 1).Load();
     radLaborLineItems.DataSource = _entity.LineItems.Local.ToBindingList();
```

In the above examples since the results are only getting filtered by the first condition I'm able to add new rows, or in other words read only is false. But when I split the conditions out, one on the load and one on the ToBindingList like this...

```
     _entity.LineItems.Where(x => x.EstID == Est.EstID).Load();
     radLaborLineItems.DataSource = _entity.LineItems.Local.ToBindingList().Where(y => y.LineItemType == 1);
```

The result is being filtered by both conditions, but I cant add a new row because of a data exception that says collection is read only. I've even tried manually setting the readonly and AllowAddNewRow properties, but still get a readonly error when trying to add a new row.

```
     radLaborLineItems.ReadOnly = false;
     radLaborLineItems.AllowAddNewRow = true;
```

So my question is how can I filter an entity by multiple conditions and still have the add new row functionality?

Also worth noting that the results are being bound to a telerik radGridView

Comment: WHy not using ...Where(x => x.EstID == Est.EstID && x.LineItemType == 1)

Comment: When I do it like that without each condition in parenthesis its only filtering by the estID and not the LineItem

Comment: @tomA The `&&` is only `true` when both sides results in `true` as well. This means you are reading only rows where the `EstID` field is set to the value of `Est.EstID` **and** the `LineItemType` value is set to `1`. If only one condition is `true` (and the other is `false`) the row is not returned. Do you want to use `||` instead?

Comment: That is what I want, every row where EstID  = Est.EstID and the LineItemType = 1. If either of these conditions are false I don't want that row. But for some reason its only reading the first condition no matter how I format it. I'm able to go into SQL and run the query with both conditions and it returns what I'm looking for

Comment: @tomA Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lineItemList = (
    from e in _entity.LineItems
    where 
        e.EstID == Est.EstID
        && e.LineItemType == 1
    select new LineItemsModel{
        e.EstId,
        e.LineItemType
    }
).ToList();

// -- Insert -- \\
lineItemList.Add(new LineItemsModel(){
    EstId = 1,
    LineItemType = 2
});

radLaborLineItems.DataSource = lineItemList;
```

Comment: It is still only filtering by the estID and not the lineItem when I try it exactly like this